# Failed to load google map api at the second times

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I am learning AngularJS and Ionic and I am adding the Google Maps API v3 to my app.

This is my controller:

```
$scope.drawMap = function(position) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.abc.lng = resp.data[0].longit;
        $scope.abc.lat = resp.data[0].latit;
        $scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: $scope.abc.lat,
                longitude: $scope.abc.lng
            },
            zoom: 17
        };
        $scope.marker = {
            id: 0,
            coords: {
                latitude: $scope.abc.lat,
                longitude: $scope.abc.lng
            }
        };
        $scope.marker.options = {
            draggable: false,
            labelAnchor: "80 120", //marker position
            labelClass: "marker-labels"
        };
    });
}
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition($scope.drawMap);
 $scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function(){
   map.remove();
 });
```

});
})

This is my HTML:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' events="map.markersEvents">
    <ui-gmap-marker coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" idkey="marker.id">
    </ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Also the directives:

```
starter.directive('googleMap', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl:"templates/google-map.html",
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs){

        }
    }
})
```

`resp.data` has a list of `latlng` of addresses, and I can load the map when I get in that page.

But when I go back to the last page, and choose another address, it cannot load the map which I can `console.log` the `latlng` of it.

Comment: Please note that there were syntax errors (unmatches closed brackets) in the code you posted. Make sure those are no errors in your full code.

Comment: thanks ! fixed the syntax errors.

Comment: you need to call map.remove() when leaving the map

Comment: Thank you! but how can i call map.remove when leaving.

Comment: I have added "ionic view.cycle" on the controller ($scope.$on) but still cannot solved the problem